# Multiple instances of @tasks.loop in cog

Tags: python, command, discord.py

I'm developping a Discord bot that scrape posts on reddit. Now I created a command so that I can fetch x amount of posts every y amount of time with @tasks.loop(time=y). Built the command in a cog, loaded it into the bot and it works as expected.

Now my problem is that as far as I understand only one instance of this command can run at once. i.e if I run the command in a server it will work fine, but I will not be able to run the command into another server until I .cancel() the running instance.

I was wondering if there was some way to have multiple instances running. Like a way to name the loop or something or if I should use another functionality of Discord.py to be able to achieve what I'm trying to do.

Edit:
I ommited some parameters in the code for simplicity's sake, but here is the code in question

```
def launch_client():
bot = Bot()
reddit = client.Client()

bot.add_cog(ScheduleCog(bot, reddit))
```

```
class ScheduleCog(commands.Cog):
    time_unit = {'seconds': 1, 'minutes': 60, 'hours': 3600, 'days': 86400, 'weeks': 604800}
    def __init__(self, bot, reddit):
        self.bot = bot
        self.reddit = reddit

    def cog_unload(self):
        self.schedule_loop.cancel()

    @tasks.loop(seconds=1)
    async def schedule_loop(self, ctx, sub, sort, limit, time):
        posts = await self.reddit.get_posts(sub, sort, limit, time)

        if posts is not None:
            for post in posts:
                await ctx.channel.send(post.url)
        else:
            await ctx.channel.send('Error in your request. Please validate fields.')

    @schedule_loop.before_loop
    async def before_schedule_loop(self):
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()

    @commands.command()
    async def subschedule(self, ctx, interval: int, interval_unit: str, sub: str, sort: str, limit: int,
                          time: str = 'hot'):
        unit: int = self.time_unit[interval_unit]
        self.schedule_loop.change_interval(seconds=interval * unit)
        self.schedule_loop.start(ctx, sub, sort, limit, time)

    @commands.command()
    async def subschedulestop(self, ctx):
        self.schedule_loop.cancel()
```

So I've written this accord to the official discord.ext.tasks [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html).

Now everything works as intended for the loop. I launch the subschedule() command and it send the posts every 'x' interval of 'y' unit of time.

Now as mentionned in the original question, is that it works in a single instance and I don't know how to have multiple instances. I want to be able to run multiple subschedule() instances in different guilds or even multiple in the same one, but as it works right now when I call the command again I get the Runtime error 'Task is already launched and is not completed'.

I simply want to know the correct method to be able to run multiple tasks in parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error said, it's not possible to start the same loop again if it's already running, but you can dynamically create new instances of `tasks.Loop`

```py
class TaskHandler(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self._tasks = [] # Empty list, holds all the loops. You can also use a dict if you want to differentiate the tasks somehow

    async def static_loop(self, *args):
        # This is the function that will be 'looping'
        print(args)

    def task_launcher(self, *args, **interval): # The `args` are the arguments passed into the loop
        """Creates new instances of `tasks.Loop`"""
        # Creating the task
        new_task = tasks.loop(**interval)(self.static_loop) # You can also pass a static interval and/or count
        # Starting the task
        new_task.start(*args)
        self._tasks.append(new_task)

    @commands.command()
    async def start_task(self, ctx, *args):
        """Command that launches a new task with the arguments given"""
        self.task_launcher(*args, seconds=1)
        await ctx.send('Task started!')
```

If you also want support for `before/after_loop`

```py
new_task = tasks.loop(**interval)(self.static_loop) # You can also pass a static interval and/or count
# Adding before/after_loop functions
new_task.before_loop(BEFORE_LOOP_FUNCTION)
new_task.after_loop(AFTER_LOOP_FUNCTION)
```